# How to compute the Retrace target for multi-step off-policy Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, deep-rl, importance-sampling

I am implementing the A3C algorithm and I want to add off-policy training using [Retrace](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02647) but I am having some trouble understanding how to compute the retrace target. Retrace is used in combination with A3C for example in the [Reactor](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04651).

I often see the retrace update written as

\begin{equation}
\Delta Q(s, a) = \sum_{t' = t}^{T} \gamma^{t'-t}\left(\prod_{j=t+1}^{t'}c_j\right) \delta_{t'}
\end{equation}

with $\delta_{t'} = r(s_{t'}, a_{t'}) + \gamma \mathbb{E}[Q(s_{t'+1}, a_{t'+1})] - Q(s_{t'}, a_{t'})$ and $c_j$ being the Retrace factors $c_j = \lambda \min(c, \frac{\pi(a_j|s_j)}{b(a_j|s_j)})$.

Now, when employing neural networks to approximate $Q_{\theta}(s, a)$ it is often easier to define a loss
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{\theta} = \left(G_t - Q(s, a)\right)^2
\end{equation}
and let the backward function and the optimizer do the update. How can I write the Retrace target $G_t$ to use in such a setup?

Is it correct to write it as follows?
\begin{equation}
G_t = \sum_{t'=t}^T \gamma^{t'-t} \left(\prod_{j=t+1}^{t'}c_j\right) (r_{t'} + \gamma Q(s_{t'+1}, a_{t'+1}) - Q(s_{t'}, a_{t'}))
\end{equation}

and then compute $\mathcal{L}$ as above, take the gradient $\nabla\mathcal{L}_{\theta}$ and perform the update step $Q(s_t, a_t) = Q(s_t, a_t) + \alpha \nabla\mathcal{L}_{\theta}$ ?